# Natural language query processing libraries

Tags: java, nlp

I am looking for Natural language query processing libraries to convert plain english query to sql like statements. For ex, show the list of employees whose age is 30 should be converted to select * from employees where age = 30.

Can you provide pointers/references?

Thanks,
Mani

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how far you want to go and the purpose of doing this. For example, do you want to handle both "whose age is 30" and "whose is 30 years-old"?

I think if you don't have too many kinds of English queries, a brute force parser against some plain English templates is a good starting point.